# How to make my apk failed to install in emulator

Tags: android

I want let my release apk file error in install to android emulator.

For example, when I install PokémonGO, the adb give me this error.
Of course, I have tried all the ABIs.

```
adb: failed to install Pokémon GO_v0.159.0_apkpure.com.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]
```

How can I make it.

Answer (score 0):

> `INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS` is when you are trying to install an
>   app that has native libraries and it doesn't have a native library for
>   your cpu architecture. For example if you compiled an app for armv7
>   and are trying to install it on an emulator that uses the Intel
>   architecture instead it will not work.

Create new emulator with x86_64 system image(ABI)

select device

select x86_64

That's it.

This error indicates the system(Device) not capable for run the application.

**EDIT**

Go to module `build.gradle` and within Android block add this script:

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips', 'mips64', 'arm64-v8a'
        universalApk true
    }
}
```

Comment: `adb devices -l:
List of devices attached
emulator-5554          device product:sdk_gphone_x86_64 model:Android_SDK_built_for_x86_64 device:generic_x86_64 transport_id:6` I tried x86_64 but it still can't install

Comment: close all emulators. Invalidate cache and restart. Then try again

Comment: I built a new emulator, but still can't install

Comment: @ikarosu_tsubasa  I'm update my answer. check it again.